# question marks appearing using xr

Tags: cross-referencing, xr

I am creating a document in LaTeX using TeXworks and I cannot get cross-referencing between separate files working. Every time I use `\ref` to a label I get two question marks.

I have three separate files: `main.tex`, `background.tex` and `implementation.tex`. The `background.tex` and `implementation.tex` files are located in a sub-directory named `sections`.

I have a label in a section within `background.tex` which I want to refer to in the `implementation.tex` file. Here is how they are defined:

#### `background.tex`:

```
\section{MySection}
\label{background:MySection}
```

to refer  to this in `implementation.tex` I write:

```
As described in section \ref{background:MySection}
```

In my `main.tex` file I use `xr` as follows:

```
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{sections/background}
```

I then compile using pdfLaTeX, then run BiBTeX for my references, then run pdfLaTeX twice. The part where I use `\ref` appears with two question marks. I get the following console output:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `background:MySection' on page 24 undefined on input line 5.
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For xr to work you must have run latex on the document that you are referencing and the aux file from that run must be available to TeX when you process the document with the reference.
In other words `sections/background.aux` must exist and have a definition for `background:MySection`

However if these are sections that are being `\input` or `\include`d into the main document, you do not want `xr` at all, just use `\label` normally.